# WCF - Unable to view Claims

Tags: wcf, claims-based-identity, wif, wcf-security, claims

My WCF method is not able to see any of my identity claims.  I'm able to authenticate the user via the ClaimsPrincipalPermission property but there's information I need out of the claim list in a given method.

The approach I'm using below works in WebForms, WebAPI, and ASMX; however, it's not working with my WCF web-methods.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Expected Results**

[image]

**Actual Results**

[image]

**WCF Method**

Again this solution works for WebForms, WebAPI, and ASMX.

```
namespace ControlPanelService
{
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    [ClaimsPrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Resource = "ControlPanel", Operation = "Request")]
    [ExceptionHandling.WCF.AiLogExceptionAttribute]
    public partial class ControlPanelService : IControlPanelService
    {
        #region Claim
        private string _testMgmtUrl { get; set; }
        private string _tmtName { get; set; }
        #endregion

        public ControlPanelService()
        {
            var identity = (System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal)System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
            this._tmtName = identity.GetClaimValue("tmtName");
        }
        
        etc...
```

**Authorization Manager (This authorizes access to the WCF methods. I am able to view the claim information here; however, once I'm in the class the claim values are missing)**

```
namespace CGI_Automation_Framework.ClaimsManager
{
    public class AuthorizationManager : ClaimsAuthorizationManager
    {
        public override bool CheckAccess(AuthorizationContext context)
        {
            var userIdentity = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
            bool checkForAuthentication = false;

            if (userIdentity.IsAuthenticated)
                return true;

            //throw new System.Web.Http.HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
            return checkForAuthentication;
        }
    }
    
    etc...
```

**Web.Config (system.identityModel)**

```
<system.identityModel>
  <identityConfiguration>
    <claimsAuthorizationManager type="CGI_Automation_Framework.ClaimsManager.AuthorizationManager, CGI_Automation_Framework" />
  </identityConfiguration>
</system.identityModel>
```

**Web.Config (WCF Behavior)**

```
<behavior name="ControlPanelServiceBehavior">
  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />      
</behavior>
```

**Web.Config (WCF Binding)**

```
<webHttpBinding>
  <binding name="DefaultBinding"
      maxReceivedMessageSize="7500000"
      maxBufferSize="7500000"
      maxBufferPoolSize="7500000">
  </binding>
</webHttpBinding>
```

**Web.Config (WCF service)**

```
<service name="ControlPanelService.ControlPanelService" behaviorConfiguration="ControlPanelServiceBehavior">
  <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="ControlPanelService.IControlPanelService" behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior" bindingConfiguration="DefaultBinding">
    <identity>
      <dns value="localhost" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</service>
```

**SVC File**

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="ControlPanelService.ControlPanelService" CodeBehind="ControlPanelService.ControlPanelService.cs" %>
```

Comment: You said that the claim value is invalid in the class, and it is valid if placed outside the class. In this case, it may be caused by insufficient authority.

Comment: Correct.  The method "CheckAccess" IS able to read all the claim values from the Identity object and the "IsAuthenticated" evaluation passes.  This class is defined in the Web.config file under the "claimsAuthorizationManager" tag.  Once the request passes this authentication check it then falls into the endpoint constructor.  Neither the constructor or the endpoint itself have access to any of the original Identity claim values. .......again the logic I'm using works fine for other .NET webservice frameworks (WebAPI and ASMX) so I'm thinking it may be with how I have WCF configured.

Comment: I found a solution to my problem.  Apparently I was referencing the wrong class.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I was trying to use the wrong method in my WCF constructor to access the claims.

The correct code to use in my WCF constructor is below:

```
    var userIdentity = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;

    IEnumerable<System.Security.Claims.Claim> c = ((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)userIdentity).Claims;
```

Again this is not how I would typically access the claims from ASMX, WebAPI, or WebForms.  Hopefully this helps someone else.